# Does C has concept of mutable and immutable values of variables like Python?

Tags: c, mutable

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        int x,y;
        x=10;
        y=x;
        x=5;
        printf("x=%d,y=%d\n",x,y);
        return 0;
}
```

**Output: x=5,y=10**

So can we say that `y` is immutable?

Comment: The value of any variable in C can be changed, unless declared `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Except `const`, all the variables values are mutable in `C`.

> So can we say that y is immutable?

The short answer: **No**.

Comment: Statically initialized strings are immutable. So, your last statement is not correct.

Comment: @DYZ I have removed that line.

Comment: @DYZ-- string literals are immutable, but statically initialized strings, i.e., strings initialized with static storage duration, are mutable. For example, `char mutable_string[] = "This may change";` at file scope, is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

> So can we say that `y` is immutable?

We can, but we'd be wrong :-)

You only have to experiment a little to find this out. A simple `y = 42` would suggest that `y` were *not* immutable but there is still some doubt in that it may have created a *new* value and pointed `y` at that, leaving the old value untouched.

This can be discounted with code like:

```
int y = 7;        // we have a y
int *pY = &y;     // and a pointer to it
y = 42;           // change y
printf ("%d %d\n", y, *pY);
```

You'll see there that *both* methods used to access `y` get the new value, indicating that the underlying value of `y` itself has changed, rather than having a new value created and `y` somehow redirected to it.

That's not to say C itself doesn't *have* immutable data, that's really what the `const` keyword is all about. However, that's rather different to Python's concept of immutability.